# How can I enable Virtualbox "skip unattended installation" when it is grayed out

Tags: virtualbox

For some reason, `Skip Unattended Installation` checkbox is grayed out (I cannot click the checkbox).

Why is it grayed out & how can I skip unattended installation?

My host machine is Manjaro & my virtualbox is version 7.

[image: Skip Unattended Installation is grayed out]

Answer (score 0):

probably not at all – it's not supported on the operating system of your choice. The way you ask this probably means you don't plan to add the necessary automation to both the Arch installer and Virtualbox by means of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already select an iso-image to install from? For me only then the setting becomes changeable:

[image]

Further Info:

I just had the issue, that I completely overlooked this setting in the initial setup of the new VM so that I unintentionally activated the "unattended installation" mode. Unfortunately it always interrupted the installation process with the error message "Product key cannot be extracted by the unattened installation process from the answer file" (or similar). I installed a new Windows 10 in my Virtual Box by the way.

This was really annoying since I didn't intended to request the unattended installation at all and also afterwards there was no clear option in the settings of the VM to disable it.

So to **overcome the issue** and **skip the unattended installation process in retrospect** I had to **delete the entire Floppy Disk/ IDE Controller from the "Storage" section in the virtual machine's settings**.

*Note: Simply removing the (**unattended-xxx-xxx-aux-iso.viso medium** from the controller didn't help, since Virtual Box automatically reassigned it after the next restart*

[image]

After this I could proceed with the manual installation process and continue to install Windows 10 successfully.